# TouchPaint Android API

Tags: java, android

All I am trying to do is use this API to write on the screen.

I am very new to programming, I can run this code, and play with it, but which class would I need to edit if I wanted to add a save button to it.

Once you draw something you would save it to your phone, how would I do this?
Can you point me to some code please?

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html